# Simple CoffeeScript for loop from End to 0

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am using CoffeeScript and I need to go through an Array from the end to the beginning in order to remove elements. It seemed like a trivial task. Here is my original code which works fine if the list length is bigger than 0 but when the list length is 0, the loop runs from -1 to 0 included.

```
list = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
length = list.length
for i in [length-1..0]
  if list[i] >= 3 and list[i] <= 5
    list.removeAt(i)
```

I isolated problem for a length 0 Array:

```
length = 0
for i in [length-1..0]
  console.log '::', i

> :: -1
> :: 0
```

In **regular JavaScript**, there would be no problem:

```
length = 0
for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  console.log('::', i)
}

// no output
```

I can't find any way to code a for loop in CoffeeScript that will behave like the JavaScript loop above.

I found an alternative solution using a while loop but it's not pretty. I would like avoiding wrapping my for loop inside an `if`. **Any way to do a CoffeeScript loop for that would behave like the simple JavaScript loop above?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your end goal is to iterate through a list in reverse order (which seems to be the case based on your original code), you can achieve this in CoffeeScript like

```
list = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
for i in list by -1
  console.log i;
```

which compiles into

```
var i, j, list;

list = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

for (j = list.length - 1; j >= 0; j += -1) {
  i = list[j];
  console.log(i);
}
```

You can [play around with it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:list%20%3D%20%5B10%2C%209%2C%208%2C%207%2C%206%2C%205%2C%204%2C%203%2C%202%2C%201%5D%0Afor%20i%20in%20list%20by%20-1%0A%20%20console.log%20i%3B) to check that it also works for empty lists.

---

If you need the index in the loop body as well, use

```
for e, i in list by -1
  console.log e  // array element
  console.log i  // array index
```

Comment: But I think they need the loop index and the array element so I think `for e, i in list by -1` would be a better fit.

Comment: Good solution, I didn't saw the 1.5.0 release note which mention it. **You can now loop over an array backwards, without having to manually deal with the indexes: `for item in list by -1`**

Answer (score 0):

You said that you need to loop from the end to the beginning so your loop in js would actually be

```
for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  console.log('::', i)
}
```

In CoffeeScript, this could be implemented as follows:

```
i = length - 1
while i >= 0
  console.log '::', i
  i--
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake in the `i--`, I made an error writing my code example. Concerning your answer, I have to quote from my question: **I found an alternative solution using a while loop but it's not pretty**.

Comment: Code isn't supposed to be pretty; it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

More `CoffeeScript` solution:

```
list = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
new_list = (i for i in list when i < 2 or i > 5)
```

or only print:

```
console.log i for i in list when i < 2 or i > 5
```

Comment: This solution do work but it create a new list of out the matching results. It's not really efficient in my case since my list is bound to my UI.